# matlab create transaction array of 0's and 1's

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

I have a header cell with 65 elements as such

```
header = 'id, item1, item2, item3, ..., item64'
```

I also have a 10000x1 cell with id's as:

```
T1  
T2  
T3
...
T10000
```

And finally I have a 1x10000 cell array with the following. For example:

```
cell{1} = 'T1' 'Item1' 'Item5'
cell{2} = 'T2' 'Item45'
...
cell{10000} = ...
```

each of variable length (variable number of items).

I need to create a matrix/array basically with the header in row 1, and each transaction in subsequent rows with a 1 if that item is in the transaction or a 0 otherwise. Like so:

```
id | item1 | item2 | item3 | ... | item64  
T1 | 0     | 1     | 0       ...
T2 | 1     | 0     | 0       ...
```

and so on so I would end up with a 65x10000 array

I have tried using the MATLAB function `ismember` but can't work out how to loop it through the array let alone create the array. I have tried creating an array of zeros but when I try to put each transaction into each row it doesn't work as the strings are of various lengths.

Thanks if anyone can shed some light on how to do this in MATLAB

Comment: Why not use a cell-matrix?

Comment: whats a cell-matrix? I know matlab has matrix types and cell types?

Comment: I mean cell-type. You will face problems when mixing strings and values in a usual matrix.

Comment: I had planned on using a cell type and so far I have each transaction in a cell but I can't get those individual strings from the cell into a matrix with 0 and 1's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified example:

```
% list of all item strings
items = strtrim(cellstr(num2str((1:6)','Item%d'))).';

% cell array of individual items for each row
cells = cell(3,1);
cells{1} = {'T1' 'Item1' 'Item5'};
cells{2} = {'T2' 'Item4'};
cells{3} = {'T3' 'Item2' 'Item3', 'Item4'};

% membership matrix
M = cell2mat(cellfun(@(c) ismember(items, c(2:end)), cells, 'Uniform',false))

% matching IDs
ids = cellfun(@(c) c{1}, cells, 'Uniform',false)
```

The result:

```
M =
     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0     0

ids = 
    'T1'
    'T2'
    'T3'
```

Comment: I can see how this works but when I do it my M is a 1x65,0000 cell, I assume that its not going to a new row each 65 items.

Comment: @GrantMcKinnon: you didn't post any working code, so I had to make my own example. We're gonna need to see how you actually build the arrays to be able to help...

Comment: thanks using what you have given I worked out a answer